# how to exit a while loop in ruby using the enter key

Tags: ruby, sorting, while-loop, break, enter

I am trying to write a program that keeps adding user input to an array until they hit enter on an empty line. Then it sorts the array in alphabetic order and display the sorted array back to you.  It is not letting me break out of the loop.
this is my code:

```
wordList = []
puts "enter as many words as you like"
entry = gets.chomp
while true
    wordList.push entry
    if entry == ''
        break
    end
end
sortedWordList = wordList.sort
puts sortedWordList
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
wordList = []
puts "Enter as many words as you like:\n"
while (entry = gets.chomp)
  break if entry.empty?
  wordList.push entry
end
puts wordList.sort
```

Answer (score 0):

```
wordList = []
puts "enter as many words as you like"
while true
  entry = gets.chomp
  wordList << entry
  if entry.blank?
    break
  end
end
sortedWordList = wordList.sort
puts wordList.inspect
puts sortedWordList
```

You'll get output something like following

```
$ ruby test.rb
enter as many words as you like
d
f
g
h
y
a
b
c
j
k

["d", "f", "g", "h", "y", "a", "b", "c", "j", "k", ""]

a
b
c
d
f
g
h
j
k
y
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine if move down `entry = gets.chomp` below the `while true`. What it is doing now is adding the first entry infinitely to the wordList.

This is a way to shorten it while maintaining readability:

```
words = []
puts "enter as many words as you like"
until (entry = gets.chomp) == ""
  words << entry
end
```